# sending Curl POSTFIELDS array

Tags: php, arrays, curl, pandadoc

I am trying to use CURL to post  the following fields to PANDADOCS, but for some reason I am getting an error that the values are not being received on their side.

This is the error I am getting:

"type": "validation_error", "detail": {"url": ["This field is required."], "name": ["This field is required."]}}

I am posting with the following:

```
$docurl = "myurl.com/document.pdf";
$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$headr[] = 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8';
$headr[] = "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN";
$url = 'https://api.pandadoc.com/public/v1/documents';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);


$postfields = array();

$postfields['name'] = 'PSA';
$postfields['url'] = $docurl;
$postfields['recipients'] = array ([0]=>array(

            ['email'] => ['dondon@gmail.com'],
            ['first_name'] => ['don'],
            ['last_name'] => ['jones'],
            ['role']=>['u1']    ));



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(  $postfields) );
$ret = curl_exec($ch); //
```

when I print_r($postfields)
I get
Array ( [name] => PSA [url] => https://api.pandadoc.com/public/v1/documents [recipients] => Array ( ) )

so all the fields arent getting posted.

but whats wierd is that the URL and NAME are in the array but not the other fields yet the error is complaining about not receiving NAME and URL..

dazed and confused...

```
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.190.72.92...
* Connected to api.pandadoc.com (54.190.72.92) port 443 (#28)
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=GT83522468; OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)14; OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R); CN=*.pandadoc.com
*    start date: 2014-11-09 00:32:24 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-10-11 09:34:58 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.pandadoc.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
*    SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> POST /public/v1/documents HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2
Host: api.pandadoc.com
Accept: */*
Content-length: 0
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS TOKEN]

* upload completely sent off: 37 out of 37 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
* Server nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 19:52:53 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept
< Allow: GET, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
< 
* Connection #28 to host api.pandadoc.com left intact
```

Comment: `$string` is never defined in your posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$string` is not defined.

Add

```
$string = http_build_query( $postfields );
```

after

```
$postfields = array();

$postfields['name'] = 'PSA';
$postfields['url'] = $docurl;

// This is invalid array
$postfields['recipients'] = array ([0]=>array(

        ['email'] => ['dondon@gmail.com'],
        ['first_name'] => ['don'],
        ['last_name'] => ['jones'],
        ['role']=>['u1']    ));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

**UPDATE**

I just read [Pandadoc API](https://www.pandadoc.com/api). They accept json data and your data was invalid. Also content type.

This should work:

```
<?php

$url                = 'https://api.pandadoc.com/public/v1/documents'; 
$docurl             = "myurl.com/document.pdf";

$postfields         = array();
$postfields['name'] = 'PSA';
$postfields['url']  = $docurl;
$postfields['recipients'] = array(
    array(
            'email'      => 'dondon@gmail.com',
            'first_name' => 'don',
            'last_name'  => 'jones',
            'role'       => 'u1'
        )
);
$data_string = json_encode( $postfields );

$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-length: '.strlen( $data_string );
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr[] = "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN";

$ch = curl_init( $url );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headr );

$result = curl_exec( $ch );

?>
```

Comment: I changed the code above but I am still getting the same 

{"type": "validation_error", "detail": {"url": ["This field is required."], "name": ["This field is required."]}}Array ( [name] => PSA [url] => myurl.com/document.pdf [recipients] => Array ( ) )

Error..

also when I print_r($postfields), the keys and values for ['recipients'] is missing

Comment: Hey those changes worked!! You are the man.  I spent all day on this and you pegged it!! You are the man!!

Comment: I tried to up vote this but I couldnt since I need 15 reputation, but you indeed answered my question.

Comment: one note to add to this, if you json_encode the parameterss, you get back an invalid url from the API because json_encode throws a backslash behind every forward slash... so I modified the code so that wont happen....

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You should still be able to mark this answer as accepted. You don't need to upvote. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)